# Computation of Partial Derivatives

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

(1)

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_] := x1^100 * x2^200 * x3^300
Derivative[1, 2, 3][f][x1, x2, x3]
```

(2) I want to get the same result as (1) when I have two lists:

```
variables = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 3}]
variableIndex = Table[i, {i, 1, 3}]
Derivative[variableIndex][f][variables]
```

But (2) doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Michael E2.

Comment: @Nasser Oops, miscopied: `Derivative[Sequence @@ variableIndex][f][Sequence @@ variables]` or `(Derivative @@ variableIndex)[f] @@ variables`.  Maybe the OP didn't test...?